# Form select change event in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have searched similar questions, but I can't find one that can solve my problem. I have angular which is working. My goal is to hide information which is not related to select option. Thanks in advance for your help.

The following jQuery code works but in angular, it doesn't in the link:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    // If form selected option changed
    angular.element('#resumeIdForm').change(function() {
        var articleIdSelected = angular.element('#resumIdFormoption:selected').val();
        var articleIdSelected = "#" + vm.articleIdSelected;

        angular.element(".articleInfo li").not(angular.element("articleIdSelected")).hide(); 
    });
});
```

Form sample:

```
<form name="" id="resumIdForm" method="post" action="">
    <label for="resumeId">Sélectionner un résumé:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="resumeId">
        <option ng-repeat="item in main.articleList" value="{{ item.articleId }} " selected="selected">{{ item.articleId }} </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Just a heads up, when using JQuery and AngularJS together you will run into issues; it's best to avoid selectors like you are currently doing and use directives/components instead.

Comment: Thank you ! That's what I'm doing. The code is placed inside a link function inside a directive

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

If you will use `if(newForm.$dirty){ // do something... }` then you will know whether user already had interactions with the form